# How to show textview after pressing delete button in custom Listview in android

Tags: android, listview, textview, custom-adapter

I have an activity named MYCartActivity.java . It contains one textview and custom listview.
How i can **show** textview When all items have deleted in listview after pressing delete button?

Below are screenshots of custom adapter.

[image]

[image]

Comment: after deleting check for if listview adapter item is 0 then set visibility of Textview to SHOW

Comment: Are you use 1.BaseAdapter with Listview 
or 2. Recyclervuew  with RecyclerView.Adapter<tHolder>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use interface:

in Adapter class.

```
public interface OnItemClick {
    void OnDelete(int position);

}
```

call OnDelete From Adapter  via Activity instance from getview() method .Like ,

```
onItemClickListener.OnDelete(position);
```

Implement that interface in Activity

```
public class A extends Activity implements Adapter.OnItemClick{

@Override
public void OnDelete(int position) {

    }
}
```

Comment: Mr. tsp, how i can call onDelete from Adapter? please guide.

Comment: please see my answer I already mention that In your adapter class take one interface with OnDelete(int position) then,  that interface method call from getView() method of your adapter. And in Activity class implement OnDelete() Method. In OnDelete method  write login which you want to implement on delete button

Answer (score 0):

On click of the delete button check if the size of the adapter is 0 or not . If it is 0 make the listview visibility gone and the textview with the message visibility Visible .

You can put the listview and textview inside a framelayout ( As parent)

Answer (score 0):

Activity fields can to available in adapter by these two ways

- Pass your Activity instance to the adapter constructor and there you can access all the fields(with access modifier: default, protected and public) of activity class.
- Make the textview as static field and can access with class name.

Answer (score 0):

While showing list `textview.setVisibility(View.GONE);`
After delete make your list null notify your adapter and change visibibilty of of your textview to `textview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)`.